# Using CardView and RecyclerView in my layout files throws an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

So I've been taking a shot at the Material Design of Android Preview L. I imported both the `CardView` and the `RecyclerView` libraries.

I use the Android Studio preview version 0.8.0. Have the latest SDK packages installed.

Once I use them in my layout files though, the previewer throws an exception for both of them.

Here is the exception for the `CardView`:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field name "CardView.Dark" in class android/support/v7/cardview/R$style
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:635)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:63)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:375)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:100)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:395)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:528)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:523)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And here is the exception for `RecyclerView`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:458)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:621)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:521)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:331)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:528)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:523)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This makes building layout near impossible using these two (amazing) `View`s, which I'm most curious about.

Is there a fix for this already, or is this actually expected behaviour seeing as they're "custom" `View`s, in a sense?

Comment: Somebody else asked about the `CardView.Dark` one earlier today, IIRC.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not mentioning the `Dark` theme anywhere. I'm just declaring the `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` tag. No `Dark` (could be a default theme). Have you had issues with it @CommonsWare?

Comment: I haven't played with it yet. I just remember seeing a mention of an issue like this earlier today here on SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio. The preview tool does not know how do initialize the widgets. I believe so, because the same exception is thrown from your app if you forget to call `recyclerView.setLayoutManager()` in your code.

Comment: You're right, I just ran into [this](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudiobetareleased) link. Android Studio seems to have updated 2 hours ago for this reason.

Comment: I installed the update. RecyclerView is still not displayed in the preview. Instead, it at least shows more meaningful error message: "The new RecyclerView does not yet work in Studio. We are working on a fix. (Open Issue 72117, Show Exception)" https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117

Comment: The CardView bug report seems to be this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79071, which also links to this change in Android Studio: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/113416/

Answer (score 8):

I am using Eclipse and faced the same issue. As suggested by user7610, you need to call `recyclerView.setLayoutManager()` to get over this.

Here is how i solved it..

Create a member variable..

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
```

In `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.business_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

This solved my `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

I found Similar Issue.
As such if we only inflate layout which consist RecyclerView then While doing setcontentView it gives error because layout manager is not set for Recyclerview Defined in Layout file.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.searchResultsList);
LinearLayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutmanager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
```

Answer (score 0):

If some one is facing the same issue for Recycler view inside fragment use this code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        String[] abc = {"hi","how are you","this is recycler"};
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(abc);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```