# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I try to use RecyclerView with RecyclerView.Adapter but here is something wrong. I post my code below:

Layout:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topic_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

topic_tile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height">

    <com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:riv_corner_radius="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_padding_top_and_bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/text_padding_top_and_bottom"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/primary_font"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_padding_left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:textSize="@dimen/secondary_font"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_padding_left"
            android:text="author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is in `onCreate()`

```
public class TitleListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RecyclerView topic_view;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private TitlelistAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_list);

        .....

        topic_view = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.topic_view);
        adapter = new TitlelistAdapter(topicList);

        topic_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(TitleListActivity.this);
        topic_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        topic_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        topic_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the Adapter:

```
public class TitlelistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TitlelistAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<Topic> topicList;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;
        TextView author;
        RoundedImageView avatar;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            author = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            avatar = (RoundedImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        }
    }

    public TitlelistAdapter(List<Topic> topicList){
        this.topicList = topicList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.topic_tile,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(topicList.get(i).title);
        viewHolder.author.setText(topicList.get(i).member.username);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return topicList.size();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1694)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it something I didn't init or something I should write more?

Answer (score 21):

I got this error when my RecyclerView had no LayoutManager. Adding this code fixed the problem:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
```

Answer (score 17):

Your xml shows that you have two android namespaces which actually should give you an error because in android you are allowed to use the namespace only once. Remove the linearLayout from your main layout as it seems unnecessary. Check your custom Row layout i.e `topic_tile` as well for any similar errors

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topic_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

EDIT :

in `onCreate()`

```
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        . 
        .
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
```

Comment: this is a mistaken but after I fixed it, the app still crashed with this exception

Comment: can you post your `topic_tile` layout file as well ?

Comment: Also if you look at this answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458538/using-cardview-and-recyclerview-in-my-layout-files-throws-an-exception  , it suggests that you should create a member variable for the `LayoutManager` class instead of `setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TitleListActivity.this));`

Comment: i think the problem is that in your `topic_tile.xml` file you have the root element as a RelativeLayout. Change that to a linear and remove the linearLayout which is the parent view for the 2 textviews.

Comment: Try playing around with the `topic_file.xml` file. The rest of the code is exactly similar as how i have implemented the RecylerView, the only thing is the custom view which you have in your xml. Try removing it and see if a view with only 2 textviews is getting inflated or not

Answer (score 11):

If your are facing the same issue for RecycleView inside a fragment, try to use this code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);

    // get recycler view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.novel_item_list);

    //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    String[] abc = {"hi","how are you","this is recycler"};
    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(abc);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much. I am also using `Fragment`s, as I suspect the original question poster was, and this must be the reason for this `NullPointerException`.

I had the code you posted (instantiating `RecyclerView`, `LinearLayoutManager`, the calls to `setLayoutManager` and `setAdapter`, etc.) in the Fragment's `onCreate()` method instead of the `onCreateView` method. Argh. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `LayoutManager` for `RecycleView`:

Currently, android supports 3 kinds of layouts.

If you want it seems a normal `ListView`, use `LinearLayoutManager`.

If you want it seems a gridView, use `GridLayoutManager`.

If you want it seem staggered, use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Constructors for 3 kinds layouts above

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);

StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

Then you set `LinearLayout` to `RecycleView` ( in this case I used `LinearLayoutManager`

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_recycle_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Anyway, use [OttoBus](http://square.github.io/otto/) Library to pass out events from the Adapter to Activity/Fragment containing the `RecycleView`.
Good luck !

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to use a ViewPager for tabs, and inside their tabs have a RecyclerView which causes this crazy error, I suggest to postpone inflating by creating yet another Fragment for including only the RecylerView.

This xml file is one of my tabs which contain a frame layout instead a recycler .

shop_most_views_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/most_view_item_frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f3f3f3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

its java class

```
public class MostViews extends Fragment {
private String title;
private int page;
View convertedView;
RecyclerView grids;

public static MostViews newInstance(int page, String title) {
    MostViews fragmentFirst = new MostViews();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    convertedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_most_views_fragment, container, false);
    transitMasonaryLayoutFragmentIntoFramLayout();
    return convertedView;
}

private void transitMasonaryLayoutFragmentIntoFramLayout() {
    MasanoryLayout masanoryLayout = new MasanoryLayout();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.most_view_item_frameLayout, masanoryLayout).commit();
}
}
```

so we have a frame layout to put our recylcer fragment into it.

shop_most_view_masanory_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/mostViewsItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

its java class

```
public class MasanoryLayout extends Fragment {
View convertedView;
RecyclerView grids;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    convertedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_most_view_masanory_fragment, container, false);
    grids = (RecyclerView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.mostViewsItem);
    setLayoutManagerOnRecyclerView();
    MasonryAdapter adapter = new MasonryAdapter(initializeData());
    grids.setAdapter(adapter);
    return convertedView;
}

private void setLayoutManagerOnRecyclerView() {
    grids.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
}

private List<StoreItem> initializeData() {
    List<StoreItem> storeItems = new ArrayList<>();
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.detailed_index_store));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.clothstore));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.detailed_index_store));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.clothstore));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.detailed_index_store));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.detailed_index_store));
    storeItems.add(new StoreItem("احسان", "احسان", R.drawable.clothstore));

    return storeItems;
}
}
```

as you see your FragmentPagerAdapter would call MostViews to be inflated and MostViews itself would call MasanoryLayout to be inflated. so we escaped FragmentPagerAdapter context ;)