# App crashing when trying to use RecyclerView on android 5.0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to mess with the new RecyclerView and whenever I try to run it, my app immediately crashes. It gives me NullPointerException for trying to access methods from `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. I've looked at other posts and saw that most people didn't have `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'` but I tried that and it hasn't helped at all. Not really sure what to do at this point, any help would be appreciated. Here the error log: (I would post a picture but I don't have 10 rep yet)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: for anyone who has this error caused by Viewpager tabs see this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34500413/2977976)

Comment: Have you solved this ?.Please help I am having same issue

Comment: Remember to set/create/register in `onCreateView` what you remove/destroy/unregister in `onDestroyView`... Gotta follow those lifecycles!

Answer (score 210, accepted):

This issue usually occurs when no [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) was provided for the [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). You can do it like so:

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I didn't set layoutManager to final.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be final so I don't think that was the problem. In my case I was implementing a fragment with recyclerView and I've tried just to retain a reference to it from onCreateView and set a layoutManager later when the data is loaded. I had this issue and it went away when I've set the layoutManager earlier in the gamein onCreateView method.

Comment: @NemanjaKovačević well, I suppose that every variable which doesn't need to be changed later has to be declared as `final`, that's why I've declared it `final` here.

Comment: Since LinearLayoutManager is vertical by default, you could use: recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

Comment: Thank God that we can Google the very same error messages that are made by Google to make sense out of them.

Comment: My issue is still present. I'm getting null object reference even with this solution.

Comment: @wesleyfranks it's hard to tell why you're getting null object reference without looking at 1. the code that sets the RecyclerView up and 2. the stacktrace you're getting after the crash. :)

Comment: Thanks, idk about anyone else but I found that taking what I'm trying to do. Put it inside it's own "app" to focus on that feature/function/etc. helps for me to figure out the problem. I'm honestly still not sure what happened, but I've been able to complete what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your response and willingness to assist.

Answer (score 26):

In my case it was not connected to 'final', but to the issue mentioned in @NemanjaKovačević comment to @aga answer.
I was setting a layoutManager on data load and that was the cause of the same crash. 
After moving the layoutManager setup to onCreateView of my fragment the issue was fixed.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: One more time: I don't tell that this issue is somehow related to variable not being final. The issue is that `LayoutManager` **wasn't provided**, that's it. You can make the variable pointing to `LayoutManager` final, or not final - it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Yurik i am using recyclerview in Activity not on fragment. what the case for me?

Comment: @Youri you should just place layoutManager setup into the onCreate of your activity, I think.

Answer (score 10):

For me, I was having the same issue, the issue was that there was an unused RecyclerView in xml with view gone but I am not binding it to any adapter in Activity, hence the issue. It was solved as soon as I removed such unused recycler views in xml

i.e - I removed this view as this was not called in code or any adapter has been set

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_profileview_allactivities"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Same here everything was perfect, but it was not working. So I removed unused recyclerviews and it worked without any issue. Thanks man @Maurice ^^

Comment: after wasting a day i tried your solution and it worked :D [ :( my time got wasted]

Answer (score 9):

I experienced this crash even though I had the `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` properly set. I had to move the `RecyclerView`  initialization code into the `onViewCreated(...)` callback to fix this issue.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listing, container, false);
    rootView.setTag(TAG);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listing, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new ListingAdapter(mListing);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Still , my issue is not resolved :/ i tried almost every solution and still getting the same error when using RecyclerView inside a fragment to be shown in PagerView :(

Comment: Awesome! Moving the `RecyclerView` initialization code into the `onViewCreated(...) ` worked

Comment: I did this solution, and it still was null for me. Still trying to figure out where though.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `setLayoutManager` in the `RecyclerView#onCreate()` method. Before adding `recyclerView` to a view, it must have the `LayoutManager` set.

```
 private RecyclerView menuAsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    menuAsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_mainMenu);
    menuAsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Home.this));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue due to wrong reference of `RecyclerView` id.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_followers_list);
```

to

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_search_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
recyclerView =
            (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
```

Check with you recycler view ID, pointing to actual recycler view solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in my XML lyout I have  an **android:animateLayoutChanges** set to true and I've called notifyDataSetChanged() on the RecyclerView's adapter in the Java code.

So, I've just removed **android:animateLayoutChanges** from my layout and that resloved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when using Butterknife library.
I had:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate
                (R.layout.fragment_recipe_detail_view, container, false);
ButterKnife.bind(rootView);
```

But the correct version is:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate
                (R.layout.fragment_recipe_detail_view, container, false);
ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Gradle** implement this library :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:SDK_VER'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:SDK_VER'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:SDK_VER'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:SDK_VER'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:SDK_VER'
```

In **XML** mention like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>
```

In **Fragment** we use `recyclerView` like this :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME, container, false);

       RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        APICallMethod();
        YOURADAPTER = new YOURADAPTER(getActivity(), YOUR_LIST); // you can use that adapter after for loop in response(APICALLMETHOD)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(YOURADAPTER);
        return rootView;
    }
```

In **Activity** we use `RecyclerView` like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        APICallMethod();
        YOURADAPTER = new YOURADAPTER(ACTIVITY_NAME.this, YOUR_LIST); // you can use that adapter after for loop in response(APICALLMETHOD)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(YOURADAPTER);
   }
```

if you need **horizontal** `RecyclerView` do this :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        APICallMethod();
        YOURADAPTER = new YOURADAPTER(ACTIVITY_NAME.this, YOUR_LIST); // you can use that adapter after for loop in response(APICALLMETHOD)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(YOURADAPTER);
```

if you want to use **GridLayoutManager** using `RecyclerView` use like this :

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3)); // 3 is number of columns.
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using a *Dependency Injection* - **ButterKnife** and this problem arised because I had not binded the view.

So inside onCreate() I just inserted this line:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

My RecyclerView declaration with Dependency Injection:

```
@BindView(R.id.recyclerview)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using: implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta05'

make sure you are using this in your xml layout

I also experienced a crash when running my app below API 27. [Here's a link to the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4eO3.png)

Originally, I have created a style to change the font size of my textview inside the recyclerview that's why I created this code below: (I could have just called @dimen when changing the font size based on screen sizes)

[Inside style.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EWCU.png)

and added this in my theme

[themes.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LNaf.png)

After investigating, I found out that this is the one causing me an error and after removing the style, I no longer experiencing a crash.

I tried all the possible solutions I found here in stack overflow and almost gave up on this, thankfully in my curiosity I thought why not removing the style maybe this causes the crash and then boom the crash is gone.

Comment: Please include code examples directly rather than linking to images. Take a look at the "Help others reproduce the problem" section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm really for this @ChrisB. This is my first time putting a comment here as my reputation is too low as you can see. I encountered the crash today and I was thinking to post here as maybe there are people who are also facing this especially they are using 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta05'.

Answer (score 0):

Since LinearLayoutManager is vertical by default, an easier way to do this is:

`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));`

If you want to change the orientation you could use this constructor:

```
public LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout);
```

Comment: having a weird issulinearlayout manager now. im instantiating it but in still ge this error. holy cow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your `Adapter`.
Make sure you have returned `ViewHolder` in `onCreateViewHolder()`.
Like below:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_leaderboard, parent, false);
    ViewHolder view_holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return view_holder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was with my activity_main.xml(21) in which the recycleView didn't have an id.

activity_main.xml(21)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/transaction_list_row" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/transac_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    />
```

It worked when i added a  android:id="@+id/transac_recycler_view" to the activity_main.xml(21) recycleView

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added only butterknife library and forget to add annotationProcessor. By adding below line to build.gradle (App module), solved my problem.

```
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview recylerview = findbyid(R.id.recyclerview)
 May be you have missed it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please explain some more why this is relevant for this question. As it is currently written it's hard to say what you are refering to.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I test my application on GenyMotion. After restart the device in GenyMotion problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue cause I had the RecyclerView in another layout and not on activity_main.xml.

By searching on some sites I got something and felt like sharing here

1. Add Id to Include tag in Activity_main.xml

   `<include id="includedRecyclerLayout"
   ....
   </include>`
2. call this layout before Searching view by ID in MainActivity.java

   `ConstraintLayout includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.inckudedRecyclerLayout);

   RecyclerViewrecyclerview=includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.RECYCLER_VIEW_ID)`;

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Butterknife , I was using fragment

For Fragment, it should be `ButterKnife.bind(this,view);`

For Activity `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

Answer (score -1):

If I where you I will do this.
onView(withId(android.R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(3));
android.R.id.list change it to your list id and position will be your position inside your array.

Answer (score -1):

> using fragment

writing code in onCreateView()

RecyclerView recyVideo = view.findViewById(R.id.recyVideoFag);

> using activity

writing code in onCreate()
RecyclerView recyVideo = findViewById(R.id.recyVideoFag);