# Android - RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener start new activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a new activity when the user touch the element in he side menu.

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //First We Declare Titles And Icons For Our Navigation Drawer List View
    //This Icons And Titles Are holded in an Array as you can see

    String TITLES[] = { "Elenco Immagini", "Come partecipare", "Il concorso", "I premi" };
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_action_account_balance,R.drawable.ic_action_event,R.drawable.ic_action_message,R.drawable.ic_action_dashboard};

    //Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header view
    //And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view

    String NAME = "Christian Giupponi";
    String EMAIL = "example@gmail.com";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.avatar_gplus;


    private Toolbar toolbar;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Assinging the toolbar object ot the view
    and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar
     */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE,this);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });


        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


                if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawers();

                    int positionClicked = recyclerView.getChildPosition(child);

                    switch (positionClicked) {
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Item Clicked is: " + positionClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Item Clicked is: " + positionClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
        });


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

In onInterceptTouchEvent I have added a switch to understand which row has been touched and I need to start a new activity.

I have tried to use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

But when I run the app it stops and this is the logcat:

```
Process: com.christiangiupponi.provamaterialdesign, PID: 2579
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:883)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-18 08:01:20.998      495-579/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '364dd98e Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-18 08:01:20.998      495-579/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3685bdbc com.christiangiupponi.provamaterialdesign/com.christiangiupponi.provamaterialdesign.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Try to set LayoutManager before you set adapter

Comment: It stops `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager
        
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Comment: I guess it stops with another stacktrace. Look here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/27419093/1788598