# RecyclerView + ViewPager NullPointerException on 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have an activity extending AppCompatActivity with a single fragment which contains RecyclerView. On any item click, it will replace this fragment with another fragment which contains ViewPager and fragments of ViewPager are again RecyclerView.

[RecyclerViewFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n99ij.png)
[ViewPagerFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zhG7.png)

I am getting following error(app crashes) on ViewPager fragment while scrolling the page.

> E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()' on a null object reference
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2022)
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2059)
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime: Process: me.twig.twigme, PID: 23451
>   E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()' on a null object reference
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2022)
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2059)
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)

Below is the code
RecyclerViewFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    cardsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cards_recycler_view);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    cardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    if(cardsRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null)
    {
        cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity(), new ArrayList<CardModel>());
        cardsRecyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
    }
    // List initialization code 
}

public static RecyclerViewFragment createInstance(String cardsJson) {

        RecyclerViewFragment cardsListFragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("cardsJson", cardsJson);
        cardsListFragment.setArguments(args);
        return cardsListFragment;
}
```

ViewPagerFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards_pager, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.removeAllTabs();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    for( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(RecyclerViewFragment.createInstance(cardsJson), "Tab title");
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            fragmentList.clear();
            fragmentTitleList.clear();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
}
```

fragment_cards.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cards_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryLight"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_cards_pager.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryLight">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: i am also stuck on this :( kindly update the post if you found any answer..!!

Answer (score 4):

From [aga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419093/2823516)

> This issue usually occurs when no LayoutManager was provided for the
>   RecyclerView. You can do it like so:
>
> ```
> final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
> layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
> recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
> ```

This solution is done programatically, but it means that you don't have any LayoutManager declared inside the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the given exception comes when the `LayoutManager` is not set on the `RecyclerView`.

I think your problem lies in following lines :

```
for( i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   pagerAdapter.addFragment(RecyclerViewFragment.createInstance(cardsJson), "Tab title");
}
```

Using the same fragment in all three adjacent views is causing errors on swiping as `ViewPager` maintains the adjacent view states for swiping behavior. Use of same ids is also known to have cause similar problems. Try checking by rendering distinct fragments.

Also, displaying the same `fragment` in all the tabs doesn't look logical.