# App crashing when trying to use RecyclerView With LayoutManager

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a data in **RecyclerView** but application crass Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference

Declaration of `RecyclerView` :

`RecyclerView rvTodos;`

`findViewByid` **of** `RecyclerView`:

```
rvTodos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTodos);
```

Here is my `SetAdapter` class:

```
private void setAdapters() {
        todosAdapter = new TodosAdapter(toDoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvTodos.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        rvTodos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvTodos.setAdapter(todosAdapter);
    }
```

Open Logcat and show the error and i click on error then it's go in this line:

`rvTodos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());`

Here is my `TodosListActivity.class`

```
public class TodosListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView txtTitle, txtClose, txtSave, txtAdd;

    String label_todos, text_add_todo;

    RecyclerView rvTodos;

    private List<ToDo> toDoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TodosAdapter todosAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_list);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        label_todos = getResources().getString(R.string.label_todos);
        txtTitle.setText(label_todos);

        txtSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSave);
        txtSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        txtClose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClose);
        txtClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtAdd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
        txtAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        text_add_todo = getResources().getString(R.string.text_add_todo);
        txtAdd.setText(text_add_todo);

        rvTodos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTodos);

        setAdapters();
        prepareToDOData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.txtAdd:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTodoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.txtClose:
                finish();
                break;

        }

    }

    private void setAdapters() {
        todosAdapter = new TodosAdapter(toDoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvTodos.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        rvTodos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvTodos.setAdapter(todosAdapter);
    }

    private void prepareToDOData() {
        ToDo data = new ToDo("David Cummings", "26/10/2017 2:25PM");
        toDoList.add(data);

        data = new ToDo("Lawrence Cummings", "26/10/2017 2:25PM");
        toDoList.add(data);


        data = new ToDo("Ketul Inc.", "11/11/2017 3:46 PM");
        toDoList.add(data);

        //notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        todosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I refer this link but it's not work for me :
[App crashing when trying to use RecyclerView on android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416834/app-crashing-when-trying-to-use-recyclerview-on-android-5-0)

It's not duplicate with [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i'll try but it's not work for me  @NileshRathod

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: is it in activity of fragments

Comment: Firstly make sure you are calling findViewById in onCreate or later and that the resource id is valid

Comment: post both your xml and java code..

Comment: i'll put findViewByid in onCreate @sshashank124

Comment: post the activity

Comment: u min java file @ALTegani

Comment: yes i mean the java file

Comment: see i update my questio @ALTegani

Comment: activity_events_list is this correct imean its the real one

Comment: @NileshRathod plz remove your comment of duplicate if anyone to know it's a same question i fully challenging the every one solve my error using this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

if not then why you assign this question is duplicate

Comment: @MohammadAli for this **`java.lang.NullPointerException`**

Comment: ya bro but it's not necessary to every `java.lanf.NullpointerExceptio` same in my error it's a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using two `reyclerView` so please check your `recyclerview Id` is it there perfect `recyclerview id` or you are assign same `id` for both of the `recyclerview` .

**Reference Code :**

Reference : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

call `prepareToDOData();` inside `setAdapters()`

```
     private void setAdapters() {
        todosAdapter = new TodosAdapter(toDoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rvTodos.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        rvTodos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvTodos.setAdapter(todosAdapter);

        prepareToDOData();//call here
    }


 private void prepareToDOData() {
        ToDo data = new ToDo("David Cummings", "26/10/2017 2:25PM");
        toDoList.add(data);

        data = new ToDo("Lawrence Cummings", "26/10/2017 2:25PM");
        toDoList.add(data);


        data = new ToDo("Ketul Inc.", "11/11/2017 3:46 PM");
        toDoList.add(data);

        //notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        todosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Why `prepareToDOData()` have to call inside `setAdapters()`? what will happen if not?

Comment: i have other class and i declare same way or class work perfectly so this is not correct answer

Comment: Are you getting runtime Exception or compile time @MohammadAli

Comment: @MohammadAli, comment that line and check are you getting any other issue ?

Comment: i got my solution in this line `rvTodos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTodos);`   i pass the wrong id so it's generate the error  @Abhishekkumar

Comment: it mean you are using same id for both of your recyclerview. Thats Why i told you to comment and check it may be some other reason for error. @MohammadAli

Comment: Welcome @MohammadAli , and also use flow as i mentioned in my answer code , happy to help you.

Comment: you update your answer with the problem so other user can access this answer @Abhishekkumar