# Recycler view crashing when trying to open in Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have an Activity which consists of RecyclerView list.

I declared recycler view as below:

```
RecyclerView listTickets = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
listTickets.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
listTickets.setHasFixedSize(true);
listTickets.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
listTickets.setAdapter(ticketListAdapter);
```

My adapter (TicketListAdapter):

```
class TicketListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
{
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_DATE:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_holder_tickets_date, parent, false);
                holder = new DateViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_TICKETS:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket_row, parent, false);
                holder =  new TicketListViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
        }
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof TicketListViewHolder){
            ((TicketListViewHolder) holder).onBind(mTicketClassListFilter.get(position), mContext, listener);
        }else if (holder instanceof DateViewHolder){
            ((DateViewHolder) holder).onBind(mTicketClassListFilter.get(position));
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below crash:

> ```
> 08-08 13:38:16.233 19159-19159/com.tcrsoftware.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.tcrsoftware.android, PID: 19159
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int)' on a null object reference
>     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1694)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:451)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:898)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23279)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2832)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1869)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2124)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7745)
>     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1694)
> ```

All are suggesting to set layout manager to recyclervie. but still there is a crash.

Comment: Are you sure there is `RecyclerView` inside your activity `layout` with id `recyclerView`?

Comment: Yes. here is the xml code:

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#bbbbbb"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

Comment: What is `SimpleDividerItemDecoration` ?

Comment: Its related to design. I removed and just tested. Still same crash.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace instead of just the first line?

Comment: Please share adapter class ticketListAdapter

Comment: updated stack trace and shared adapter snippet

Comment: does using extends Activity instead of Appcompactactivity causes this issue?

Comment: If possible share the complete code of **activity, adapter and layout.**

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416834/app-crashing-when-trying-to-use-recyclerview-on-android-5-0) out

Comment: Make `listTickets` global variable or field and move all the code directly inside `onCreate` just leave part `listTickets.setAdapter(ticketListAdapter);`. So all code above that line cut and paste inside `onCreate` directly below `setContentView` just to make sure you are not calling any method for setting adapter before setting the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes @Yupi. Your solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: @sai great I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to your layout manager. Instead, use the following code as per the following order.

```
 RecyclerView listTickets = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
 listTickets.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
 listTickets.setAdapter(ticketListAdapter);
```

I have omitted some code so that you can use the important bits first and add the more details after.

Comment: @sai the log cat points to layout manager but the code looks fine, the easier way is to use a single viewholder in the adapter so you can see where the problem will popup. since the code will be too much on the question, you can host the adapter, viewholder, model and mainactivity on github and i will edit for you. share the link on the question too for others to view

Comment: can you check this

Comment: @Lucem  your Answer is acceptable (Y),
update LayoutManager like this:-
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
OR
You can set like this
rvLeftMenu.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: Thanks for responses. This and @Yupi solution helped solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your adapter by following its constructor in your activity.
For example:

```
//Your adapter constructor:
class TicketListAdapter(Context context){
      this.context = context
}
```

Example of initializing adapter in your activity:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
listTickets.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
ticketListAdapter = new TicketListAdapter(this);
listTickets.setAdapter(ticketListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

So after looking into your code I noticed that there was possibility that adapter was set before `RecyclerView` is connected with its `id` so consider changing some things inside your code: 
Make `listTickets` global variable or field and move all the code directly inside `onCreate` just leave part `listTickets.setAdapter(ticketListAdapter);`. So all code above that line cut and paste inside `onCreate` directly below `setContentView` just to make sure you are not calling any method for setting adapter before setting the `RecyclerView`.