# What Should I Do with the error RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android

I want to fetch images from mysql server into recycler view. When I run my app. I face the following problem:

> 02-25 19:47:47.075 653-12579/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release
>   without a matched acquire! 02-25 19:47:53.241 69-403/? E/FastThread:
>   did not receive expected priority boost 02-25 19:47:53.393
>   14523-14523/com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter
>   attached; skipping layout 02-25 19:47:53.466
>   14523-14523/com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp E/EventBus: Could not
>   dispatch event: class
>   com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp.serverclasses.GalleryEventBus to
>   subscribing class class
>   com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp.GalleryActivity
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp.GalleryActivity.onMessageEvent(GalleryActivity.java:131)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:507)
>           at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:434)
>           at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:411)
>           at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:384)
>           at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:265)
>           at com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp.serverclasses.GetImages$1.onResponse(GetImages.java:59)
>           at com.example.wiqarali.tourismapp.serverclasses.GetImages$1.onResponse(GetImages.java:37)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

Here is my event bus code

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(GalleryEventBus eventBus){
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView_gallery.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView_gallery.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, eventBus.galleryList);
    recyclerView_gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you

Comment: You can try like this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416834/app-crashing-when-trying-to-use-recyclerview-on-android-5-0](Link)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation as you and I've just fixed it.
In my case, when initiate `RecyclerView` I only set adapter if data.size() > 0. Then after that when you receive event and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` causing that error

```
  if (data.size() > 0) {
            rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));
            rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
  }
```