# Cause for NullPointerException android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I am getting following Exception

```
01-27 11:15:15.756  18348-18348/com.example.pnimje.newswipelistview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and RecyclerView.java:1764 is

```
    mLayout.onMeasure(mRecycler, mState, widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

Why is mLayout (LayoutManager) null?

Comment: I'm guessing because somewhere along the line, it got set to null or was never not null. You're going to need to show more code than that.

Comment: for anyone who has this error caused by Viewpager tabs see this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34500413/2977976)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

because you have not set LinearLayoutManager to RecyclerView.

for example:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
```

Comment: into fragment - new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity)

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of errors usually originate in **not setting the RecyclerView's layout manager**. Bein' in a hurry myself I forgot to set one which ended in the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:1636)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1820)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2177)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1878)
```

The following line should resolve it:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((Activity)this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Antón response is good but can be confusing in beginners like me, talves this serves to clarify some doubts.

```
RecyclerView rv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar);

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecViewTest);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that what you are sending to the adapter is not an empty `List<Type>`. I recommend you to either create the `RecyclerView` by code and add it later when you have the information, or to put an empty `NULL` object before passing it to the constructor of the adapter.