# How determine NullPointerException with less log information to own source code?

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

On program execution, I get the error message:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main   E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): java.lang.NullPointerException`.

The bottom messages gives only a small hint to the self written source code. But there is missing a detailed information to the line number of incorrect code. Which possibilities exist to get a log output with more specific information to the root reason of the exception?
In this question I don't like to know what is the mistake in the code. My question is:

*What is to be done to detect the mistake of code himself?*

For example, can more information be queried with the android debug manager? Or what other possibilities exist?
It is javac command line programming. Android Studio shall not be used. I hope the basic options of debug solution should be independent of the use of using an IDE or not.

For the current example, here is the log output:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 2977): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa5000678)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:5555)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1332)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2977): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm( 2977): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 26% free 2638K/3556K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 10ms
W/ActivityManager( 1448):   Force finishing activity com.mypackage/.PopupWindow
I/WindowManager( 1448): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{a592d048 ActivityRecord{a56d4960 u0 com.mypackage/.PopupWindow}} appWin=Window{a5503378 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.PopupWindow} drawState=1
W/WindowManager( 1448): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (1080x1920) to layer 21015
```

Comment: Also please take look into similar exception posts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179494/cause-for-nullpointerexception-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview-onmeasure