# RecycleView using GridLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I got this exception using recyclingView in a Fragment:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is already a solution for this kind of bug:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737113/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview-onmeasu)

Using this code everything works as it should but the thing is that I want to use a GridLayout instead.

```
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3); 

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); ...
```

I have already debugged but GridLayoutManager in not null...

Please I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the Recyclerview like:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(
    R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new myAdapter(count));
```

Source: [Recyclerview Gridlayout](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this before setting adapter to recyclerView

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);